# Piecewise function using Quantity is returning a Piecewise answer

Tags: piecewise, units

```
i[t_] = Piecewise[{{Subscript[I, 1]/Subscript[t, 1] t, 
Quantity[0, "Seconds"] < t <= Subscript[t, 1]}, {Subscript[I, 1], 
Subscript[t, 1] < t < Subscript[t, 2]}, {Subscript[I, 1] - 
 Subscript[I, 1]/(
  Subscript[t, 4] - Subscript[t, 3]) (t - Subscript[t, 2]), 
Subscript[t, 2] <= t <= Subscript[t, 4]}}, Quantity[0, "Amperes"]]
```

When I run this function and try an input like

```
i[Quantity[3, "Seconds"]]
```

it returns a piecewise answer which includes the correct answer but also the general True answer.

Comment: You can't use `I` as a variable because Mathematica reads it as `Complex[0,1]` or `Sqrt[-1]`

Comment: You can if it has an underscore. At least, it's been working like that for me for all my other problems.

Comment: Your troubles are almost assuredly caused by your use of Subscript. The function returns a piecewise result because it cannot determine which right hand side is True.  What is definition of $t_1$ for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is slightly different than your question.

Using the function definitions from your answer and setting `t` to 3 seconds

```
i[Quantity[3, "Seconds"]]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the solution using subscripts is taking `QuantityMagnitude[Subscript[t, 1]]` and setting it equal to "3 Seconds" (i.e., the input value of `t`) with a subscript of 1!! The same happens to all of the other `t` with subscripts.

I don't think that is what you had in mind (was it?).

Below is a definition that doesn't use subscripts (the folks here are trying to help you by indicating that using subscripts as symbols is a road to disaster). Also you are looking for trouble if you use `I` rather `i` as a variable.

```
iN[t_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {i1/t1 Quantity[t, "Seconds"], 0 < t <= QuantityMagnitude[t1]},
   {current, t < QuantityMagnitude[t2]}
   },
  i1 - i1/(t4 - t3) (Quantity[t, "Seconds"] - t2)
  ]
```

Using `iN` with `t` set to 3 seconds

```
iN[Quantity[3, "Seconds"]]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work as one function, but I found a workaround using multiple functions.

```
Subscript[i, 1][t_] = 
    Subscript[I, 1]/Subscript[t, 1] Quantity[t, "Seconds"]; 
Subscript[i, 2][t_] = 
    Subscript[I, 1] - Subscript[I, 1]/(
    Subscript[t, 4] - Subscript[t, 
    3]) (Quantity[t, "Seconds"] - Subscript[t, 2]); 


i[t_] = Piecewise[{{Subscript[i, 1][t], 
0 < t <= QuantityMagnitude[Subscript[t, 1]]}, {Subscript[current, 
1], t < QuantityMagnitude[Subscript[t, 2]]}}, Subscript[i, 2][t]];
```